# Override form element twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I want to override the twig template for specific fields on a form which I created via the Contact module in Drupal 8.

However, I can't find any documentation, and the suggestions in the HTML comments also doesn't show me anything useful.

Basically I want to override, a custom field (field_phone) and a standard field (Sender name) on a specific contact form the following values:

- form-element.html.twig
- form-element-label.html.twig
- input.html.twig

Is that possible? And what are the file name suggestions?

Comment: It should be field--field-phone.html.twig for field named field_phone. Copy the template from core/modules/system/templates/field.html.twig into your theme

Comment: That I know, but I want it only for that form, not for everywhere the phone field is used.

Comment: I guess I would use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter, find the field and set #theme to 'field__myphone_field' so that you can use field--myphone-field.html.twig template.

Answer (score 8):

The [Drupal Themable Forms module](https://www.drupal.org/project/themable_forms) adds some helpful theme suggestions for form elements that are missing from core.

The added theme suggestions for form elements are:

```
  form-element--[form-id]--[element-type].html.twig
  form-element--form-id--[form-id].html.twig
  form-element--type--[element-type].html.twig
  form-element.html.twig
```

Comment: Note that this currently does not work for targeting checkboxes in different forms.

Comment: Doesn't work for checkbox/radio buttons.

Comment: Looks like there is a patch for checkboxes now https://www.drupal.org/project/themable_forms/issues/2887429

Answer (score 8):

No need to install an extra module, you could just add the suggestions by yourself:

file: *MYMODULE.module*

```
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if ( $variables['element']['#id'] === 'FORMID') {
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__custom';
  }
}
```

this will make Drupal look for a twig file named '**form-element--custom.html.twig**'

$hook is 'form_element' in this case, as we are explicitly hooking into it, the function name is '*MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter*', but you could just choose **any arbitrary name** for the template file, i just tried to stick to the Drupal naming conventions.

To find out the FORMID for your specific form just add the following line as the first line of the function and then inspect the element in the browser, there you will see an html comment with the name of the form.

```
  print '<-- FORMID:'.$variables['element']['#id'].'-->';
```

Comment: Form ID is doesn't seem to be available inside this function

Comment: In Drupal 8.5.x it leads to Notice: Undefined index: #id in custom_barrio_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter() (line 48 of themes/custom/custom_barrio/custom_barrio.theme).

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach:

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . $variables['element']['#id'];
  $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . $variables['element']['#type'];
}
```